# MySQL How do I join and select visible records from one table?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to fix some data by adding a new field.

I have a backup from a few months ago and I have restored this database to my server.

I'm looking at table called pads, its primary key is PadID and the field of importance is called RemoveMeDate.  In my restored (older) database there is less records with an actual date set in RemoveMeDate. My control date is 2001-01-01 00:00:00 meaning that the record is not hidden aka visible.

What I need to do is select all the records from the older database / table with the control date and join with those from the newer db /table where the control date is not set.

I hope I've explained that correctly.

I'll try again, with numbers.  I have 80,000 visible records in the older table (with control date set) and 30,000 in the newer db/table. I need to select the 50,000 from the old database, to perform an update query.

Heres my query, which I'd can't get to work as I'd like.  jules-fix-reasons is the old database, jules is the newer one.

```
select p.padid 
from `jules-fix-reasons`.`pads` p
JOIN `jules`.`pads` ON p.padid = `jules`.`pads`.`PadID` 
where p.RemoveMeDate <> '2001-01-01 00:00:00' AND 
`jules`.`pads`.RemoveMeDate =     '2001-01-01 00:00:00'
```

EDIT - Perhaps I can provide an example, instead of a 10,000 records I'll show 1 example.

```
p.pads (old table)
PadID=1 RemoveMeDate=2010-12-01 09:00:00
PadID=2 RemoveMeDate=2001-01-01 00:00:00
PadID=3 RemoveMeDate=2001-01-01 00:00:00
PadID=4 RemoveMeDate=2001-01-01 00:00:00
PadID=5 RemoveMeDate=2001-01-01 00:00:00
PadID=6 RemoveMeDate=2001-01-01 00:00:00
PadID=7 RemoveMeDate=2001-01-01 00:00:00
PadID=8 RemoveMeDate=2001-01-01 00:00:00
PadID=9 RemoveMeDate=2001-01-01 00:00:00
PadID=10 RemoveMeDate=2009-01-05 00:10:00
```

So theres 8 (aks=a 80,000 in the real table) records visible.

```
Jules.pads
PadID=1 RemoveMeDate=2010-12-01 09:00:00
PadID=2 RemoveMeDate=2010-12-01 08:00:00
PadID=3 RemoveMeDate=2010-12-01 07:00:00
PadID=4 RemoveMeDate=2010-12-01 06:00:00
PadID=5 RemoveMeDate=2001-01-01 00:00:00
PadID=6 RemoveMeDate=2001-01-01 00:00:00
PadID=7 RemoveMeDate=2001-01-01 00:00:00
PadID=8 RemoveMeDate=2001-01-01 00:00:00
PadID=9 RemoveMeDate=2001-01-01 00:00:00
PadID=10 RemoveMeDate=2009-01-05 00:10:00
```

So theres 5 (aks=a 50,000 in the real table) records visible.

So the SQL query I want would return records 2,3,4 from table P

Edit ajreal - working query (FYI)

```
SELECT old_table.padid
FROM `jules-fix-reasons`.`pads` AS old_table
JOIN `jules`.`pads` AS new_table ON old_table.padid = new_table.`PadID`
WHERE new_table.RemoveMeDate <> '2001-01-01 00:00:00'
AND old_table.RemoveMeDate = '2001-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: What do you get when you run this?

Comment: I don't get any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I need to do is select all the records from the **older database / table with the control date** and **join with those from the newer db /table where the control date is not set**.

you just need to flip the condition

```
select old_table.padId, new_table.padId
from `jules-fix-reasons`.`pads` as old_table
JOIN `jules`.`pads` as new_table
ON old_table.padid = `jules`.`pads`.`PadID`
where new_table.RemoveMeDate<>'2001-01-01 00:00:00' AND 
old_table.RemoveMeDate='2001-01-01 00:00:00'
```

**PS:** is time to learn how to give a good name for your table alias

Comment: I did try to add an alias for the other table but it didn't work. I think that works, but I'm a bit puzzled. Your query returns 54,180 records. The old table has 83,132 records and the new table has 30,834. If I minus old from new I get 52,298. I'm not sure why there's a difference, any ideas ? What does the logic say ?

Comment: it could be some of your records overlapped each other, try `select count(*) from old_table where RemoveMeDate='?';` and `select count(*) from new_table where RemoveDate<>'?';`

Comment: If I use 2001-01-01 00:00:00 I get 83,132 and 30,834 as above. Any further ideas?

Comment: any chance either table contains multiple record for the same padId? you can verified `select padId from tables group by padId having count(*)>1;`

Comment: No its a unique index. Granted there will be more records in the new table, but not sure if that would explain it.